# AWS CloudSearch request using CLI returns Invalid Javascript Object error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to query my AWS Cloudsearch (2013 API) domain using the AWS CLI on Ubuntu. I haven't been able to get it to work successfully when the search is restricted to a specific field. The following query:

```
aws --profile myprofile cloudsearchdomain search   
    --endpoint-url "https://search-mydomain-abc123xyz.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com"  
    --query-options {"fields":["my_field"]}  
    --query-parser "simple"  
    --return "my_field"  
    --search-query "foo bar"
```

...returns the following error:

> An error occurred (SearchException) when calling the Search operation: q.options contains invalid javascript object

If I remove the `--query-options` parameter from the above query, then it works. From the [AWS CLI docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearchdomain/search.html) regarding the `fields` options of the `--query-options` parameter:

> An array of the fields to search when no fields are specified in a search... Valid for: simple , structured , lucene , and dismax

aws cli version:

> aws-cli/1.11.150 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.10.0-28-generic botocore/1.7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the documentation is a bit misleading as JSon does not like embedded double quotes inside double quotes, you would need to replace with single quote as

```
--query-options "{'fields':['my_field']}"
```

or you can escape the double quote

```
--query-options "{\"fields\":[\"my_field\"]}"
```